# Apply a transformation to a group of rows in one row meets a criteria MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'd like to apply a simple transformation to a group of common rows, if one row meets a particular criteria.

For example, in the following data, I'd like to add 1 to each Value for any ID that has a value of 0... for all of his values such that this data

```
Value  ID    
2      1
3      1
0      2
1      2
```

would transform to this...

```
Value  ID
2      1
3      1
1      2
2      2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrg.  This is MySQL.  You can do this with a `join`:

```
update t join
       (select distinct t2.id
        from t t2
        where t2.value = 0
       ) t2
       on t2.id = t.id
    set t.value = t.value + 1;
```

Comment: I probably should have said the table is a Temporary table - update does not play nicely with temp tables - any workaround?

Comment: @gh0strider18 . . . Oops.  I very much know that.  The solution then is to use `join`.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still getting the 1137 Error where mySql cannot reopen temp table. Again, I think it's an update error...

Comment: @gh0strider18 . . . That is a strange error.  `update` with `join` does work.

Comment: What I ended up doing is `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0` and that fixed the error - thanks for help!